# Калькулятор. Нужно сделать подсчет по checkbox

Tags: post, php, html

Добрый день! Необходимо сделать калькулятор, когда checkbox = checked, то идет сложение.

```
if (!empty($_POST['htmlcss']) && !empty($_POST['SEO']) && !empty($_POST['design'])) {
   if ($_POST['htmlcss'] == как узнать что checked?) {
       $calc = "";
   }
   if ($_POST['SEO'] == как узнать что checked?) {
       $calc .= $_POST['htmlcss'] + $_POST['SEO'];
   }
   if ($_POST['design'] = как узнать что checked?) {
       $calc .= $_POST['htmlcss'] + $_POST['SEO'] + $_POST['design'];
   }echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"{$calc}\" />";
}else{
    require_once (ENGINE_DIR . '/data/price.php');
    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"./\">";
echo "Цена на верстку HTML+CSS: <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"htmlcss\" checked><label for=\"check1\" />{$pricecfg['htmlcss']} руб.</label><br/>";
echo "Цена SEO: <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"seo\"><label for=\"check1\" />{$pricecfg['SEO']} руб.</label><br/>";
echo "Цена Design: <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"design\"><label for=\"check1\" />{$pricecfg['design']} руб.</label><br/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Подсчитать\">";
echo "</form>";

}
echo $result;
```

Вот, что я написал.

Как можно реализовать?

Comment: мой тебе совет, скачай книгу по php

Comment: if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
        $sum = 0;
            foreach ($_POST['val'] as $k=>$v) {
                $sum += $v;
            }
                echo "Общая цена " . $sum . "руб.";
    }
Написал по-другому, все отлично

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once (ENGINE_DIR . '/data/price.php');
echo "<form method=post>";
echo "html+css верстка: {$pricecfg['htmlcss']} руб. <input type=checkbox name=\"val[]\" value='{$pricecfg['htmlcss']}'><br/>";
echo "Продвижение сайта: {$pricecfg['SEO']} руб. <input type=checkbox name=\"val[]\" value='{$pricecfg['SEO']}'><br/>";
echo "Уникальный дизайн: {$pricecfg['design']} руб. <input type=checkbox name=\"val[]\" value='{$pricecfg['design']}'><br/>";
echo "Натяжка на CMS: {$pricecfg['cms']} руб. <input type=checkbox name=\"val[]\" value='{$pricecfg['cms']}'><br/>";
echo "<input type=submit name=btn>";
echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
        $sum = 0;
            foreach ($_POST['val'] as $k=>$v) {
                $sum += $v;
            }
                echo "Общая цена " . $sum . "руб.";
    }
```

Решил сам, всем спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

`checked` - логическое свойство. Просто для чекбокса создайте обработчик события `Onclick` и там в нем определяйте, выбран или нет.

```
onClick="if (this.checked) {//}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Я у checkbox'ов ловил "checked" так:

HTML:

```
<input name='select_task' type='checkbox' checked='checked' value='X'>
```

Потом ловил значение через POST[]

PHP:

```
$select_task = @$_POST["select_task"];
```

Получал X.